# how to update version of current Installed Deno

Tags: deno

i installed vesion of 1.10.2 on my pc and i want to use last vestion of deno so
How can i update version of deno ?

should I use install command  and install it again
or there is something like

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Updating | Manual | Deno](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/installation#updating):

> To update a previously installed version of Deno, you can run:
>
> ```
>  deno upgrade
> ```